# How to do an action when a new data comes from API

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I'm fetching some data from an API and displaying it in a list. When that API update data, I want to reproduce a sound, how can I do that?

I tried to use Streams to implement that, but it wasn't successful.

Comment: Is the api yours, or third party?

Comment: The API is mine

Comment: try sending a request from the client side, which tells it to check every 0.1 second for change. once it happens, send back a response to the initial request.